# Troubleshooting "loopback requests that take too long"

Tags: php, loop, errors, editor

So I am dealing with this dreaded "unable to edit php files" errors after updating to 4.9.1

I disabled all of my plugins, and I am still getting the following error though the [Health Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin:

> The loopback request to your site took too long to complete, this may
>   prevent WP_Cron from working, along with theme and plugin editors.

Which is great to know!

Because apparently that is the cause of the error that I receive when I try to edit php files from inside the wordpress editor which is:

> Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the
>   PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change
>   by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

So where can I look to fix it now?

If every single plugin is disabled, it must be a problem with my theme?

I am running a theme that I made from scratch based off of underscores.me

If I am not running any plugins at all, and my loopback requests are still taking too long, how can I remedy that situation?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I can edit .css files on my current theme. And I can edit any file on another theme that is not currently active. I just cannot edit php files on my currently active theme... which makes me think it's related to this loopback request stuff.

EDIT 2: Are loopback requests actual http requests that look for a copy of my site online? Because if so... the site is actually offline right now. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem until I working with my localhost. After uploading, I was able to edit css files but not php files. after a lot of research, I found problem source is enabling  HTTPS protocol. I changed url to normal HTTP and everything was good.
After some research, finally enabling openssl extension in php.ini file, resolved my probleem

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

I edited line 492 of wp-admin/includes/file.php right now:

FROM

```
if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension ) {
```

TO

```
if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension && false) {
```

And now I am able to edit my hidden website's theme files just as I was prior to updating to 4.9! Yippee!

Comment: editing core files is never the answer.